# Combine two shell commands into one output in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to combine multiple commands into a single output.

```
#!/bin/bash

x=$(date +%Y)
x=$($x date +m%)

echo "$x"
```

This returns

> ./test.sh: line 4: 2011: command not found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x=$(echo $(date +%Y) $(date +%m))
```

(Note that you've transposed the characters `%` and `m` in the month format.)

Comment: There's no point using echo like that -- it doesn't add anything since you're just giving it a string and then capturing that same string again. You can just do `x="$(date +%Y) $(date +%m)"`

Comment: @John Bartholomew, you're right, it's a habit because I tend immediately to pipe echo to sed, etc.

Answer (score 5):

In the second line, you're trying to execute `$x date +m%`. At this point, $x will be set to the year, 2011. So now it's trying to run this command:

```
2011 date +%m
```

Which is not what you want.

You could either do this:

```
x=$(date +%Y)
y=$(date +%m)

echo "$x $y"
```

Or that:

```
x=$(date +%Y)
x="$x $(date +%m)"

echo "$x"
```

Or simply use the final date format straight away:

```
x=$(date "+%Y %m")
echo $x
```

Comment: You have a typo/copy-paste error: you're still using `$y` in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
#!/bin/bash

x=$(date +%Y)
x="$x$(date +%m)"

echo "$x"
```

...also correcting what appears to be a transpose in the format string you passed to `date` the second time around.

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon to separate commands on the command line.

```
date +%Y ; date +m%
```

Or if you only want to run the second command if the first one succeeds, use double ampersand:

```
date +%Y && date +%m
```

Or if you want to run both commands simultaneously, mixing their output unpredictably (probably not what you want, but I thought I'd be thorough), use a single ampersand:

```
date +%Y & date +%m
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ´date +%Y´ ´date +m%´
```

Note the reverse accent (´)

Comment: Except that you're using the wrong character. And `$()` is preferred.

Comment: Thanks, while I answer the question I was on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo `date +%Y` `date +%m`
```

And to make the minimum change to the OP:

```
x=$(date +%Y)
x="$x $(date +%m)"
echo "$x"
```